# How to save an image via rvest in R?

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I would like to save all XL png files in a website via rvest. However the image can not be opened.
for example
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
s <- html_session("https://www.countryflags.com/en/china-flag-image.html")

imgsrc <- s %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*/a[@href='//cdn.countryflags.com/download/china/flag-png-xl.png']") %>% 
  html_attr('href')
img <- jump_to(s, imgsrc)
writeBin(img$response$content, basename(imgsrc))
```

I would like to know why download.file function or code above is not working

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Rselenium` library

Here a possible soltuion and some deeping.

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium)

[Presentation](http://johndharrison.github.io/RSOCRUG/#1)

```
        library(RSelenium)
        
        #We start the RSelenium environment
        driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"),port = 4444L)
        remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]  
        
        #We send the url to the firefox browser
        remote_driver$navigate("https://www.countryflags.com/en/china-flag-image.html")
        
            for (i in 3:18) {
            #We use the trycatch function to manage the xpath that the system doesn't find
              tryCatch(expr ={
              #We create a xpath dynamic
              flag<-  paste0('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[',i,']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a')
              #By the function findElement we find the dynamic xpath             
              remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", flag)$clickElement()},
              #If the xpath is not present print the message not found!
              error = function(e){          
              message('not found!')})
              }
```